# sharepoint 2013 wcf service The HTTP request is unauthorized

Tags: windows, wcf, sharepoint-2013

I'm using wcf service hosted on iis7 over https and when i call service in windows 8 app it returns error

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'."

this service web.config

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CellStorageServiceBehavior" name="Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.CellStorages">
    <endpoint address="CellStorageService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="StreamBinding" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />
    <endpoint address="CellStorageServiceBasic" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingBasic" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />
    <endpoint address="CellStorageServiceDigest" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingDigest" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />
    <endpoint address="CellStorageServiceNtlm" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingNtlm" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="CellStorageServiceHttpsBehavior" name="Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.CellStoragesHttps">
    <endpoint address="CellStorageService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingHttps" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />

    <endpoint address="CellStorageServiceBasic" binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingHttpsBasic" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />

    <endpoint address="CellStorageServiceDigest" binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingHttpsDigest" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />

    <endpoint address="CellStorageServiceNtlm" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingHttpsNtlm" contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ClaimProviderWebServiceBehavior" name="Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SPClaimProviderWebService">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="TextStreamBindingNoSecurity"
              bindingNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/claims/"
              behaviorConfiguration="HttpBinding.LargeDataEndpointBehavior"
              contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="HttpsClaimProviderWebServiceBehavior" name="Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SPClaimProviderWebServiceHttps">
    <endpoint address=""
              binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="TextStreamBindingHttpsNoSecurity"
              bindingNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/claims/"
              behaviorConfiguration="HttpBinding.LargeDataEndpointBehavior"
              contract="MOL.Service.ISAPI.MOL.IServiceHosted" />
  </service>
</services>
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="https" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamBindingHttps" />
  <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="StreamBinding" />
</protocolMapping>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
           crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="StreamBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="StreamBindingBasic" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="StreamBindingDigest" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Digest"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="StreamBindingNtlm" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="TextStreamBindingNoSecurity" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Text"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
    </binding>
    <binding name="StreamBindingHttps" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="StreamBindingHttpsBasic" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="StreamBindingHttpsDigest" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Digest"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="StreamBindingHttpsNtlm" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Mtom"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="TextStreamBindingHttpsNoSecurity" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="true"
      maxBufferSize="4194304" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" messageEncoding="Text"
      transferMode="StreamedResponse">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="mexHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
    <binding name="mexNtlmHttpBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<!--For debugging purposes set the includeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute to true-->
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CellStorageServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

    </behavior>
    <behavior name="CellStorageServiceHttpsBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ClaimProviderWebServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="HttpsClaimProviderWebServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HttpBinding.LargeDataEndpointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

and this way to call service from windows 8 app

```
private async void ConfigureHttpsProxy()
    {
        try
        {
            SecurityBindingElement securityElement = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
            HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsTransport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            httpsTransport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;

            CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(securityElement, httpsTransport);
            binding.Name = "StreamBindingHttps";

            EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress(addressHttps);

            var client = new ServiceHosted.ServiceHostedClient(binding, remoteAddress);
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";

            client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            var result = await client.GetUserAsync("ahmed", "123456");

            var x = result.DepartmentName;
        }
        catch { }          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

after weeks of search result was as below:

NTLM solution steps:
1-  From center admin:
Center administration:
NT Authority\local -> full control
current user -> full control

Authentication Provider
claims Based Authentication -> Default
Enable anonymous access
Enable windows -> Kerberos

2-  From web config:
Add the following node to the service’s serviceBehaviors behavior node.

3-  From client side:
 _serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                _serviceClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;

4-  From service side:
Enable impersonation at the web site.  Either enable ASP.NET impersonation for the entire site or temporarily impersonate the user from within the web site by using WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(token).
Add the following attribute to each method in the WCF service that needs impersonation.
     [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]

for more details back to links :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/11/04/double-hop-windows-authentication-with-iis-hosted-wcf-service.aspx